# Explanation of Drools Rules in NurseRostering application

Tags: drools, rules, optaplanner

I am facing issues in understanding the Drools rules which are implemented in one of the OptaPlanner demo example (NurseRostering application). Can anyone explain how the below rule works :

```
// a nurse can only work one shift per day, i.e. no two shift can be assigned to the same nurse on a day.
rule "oneShiftPerDay"
when
    $leftAssignment : ShiftAssignment($leftId : id, $employee : employee, $shiftDate : shiftDate)
    $rightAssignment : ShiftAssignment(employee == $employee, shiftDate == $shiftDate, id > $leftId)
then
    insertLogical(new IntConstraintOccurrence("oneShiftPerDay", ConstraintType.NEGATIVE_HARD,
            1,
            $leftAssignment, $rightAssignment));
end
```

Are there any resources which states in detail about the explanation of the rules and the way they are implemented? When I check some of the examples online and in some books, i find it pretty easy to understand, however when i check the samples provided in Drools, i am unable to get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
when
    // When a specific shift with id $leftId is assigned to employee $employee and that shift is on date $shiftDate
    $leftAssignment : ShiftAssignment($leftId : id, $employee : employee, $shiftDate : shiftDate)
    // AND there is another shift assigned to the same for the same date and with a higher id
    $rightAssignment : ShiftAssignment(employee == $employee, shiftDate == $shiftDate, id > $leftId)
then
    // Then this solution is penalized: it gets -1 hard score point
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
```

Note: In the then side, I used the [OptaPlanner](http://www.optaplanner.org/) 6 syntax (instead of the deprecated Planner 5.x syntax), because it's [faster and easier](http://blog.athico.com/2013/04/score-drl-faster-and-easier-in.html).

About the `id < $leftId` part: this to make sure that Drools only matches ShiftAssignment A with ShiftAssignment B (which gives A-B) and not A-A, B-B, B-A too, to avoid penalizing too much.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of learning the syntax of the DRL, I recommend to read the Drools documentation here:

http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.0.CR1/drools-expert-docs/html/ch04.html

For my understanding it helped me a bit more than the OptaPlanner/Drools Planner Docs regarding the rule settings.